# Is it possible to create a custom condition equivalate of @ConditionalOnMissingBean with Spring (no spring-boot)?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to implement a Spring condition that will load my bean only if there is no other beans for a certain class.
The desired behavior is similar to "@ConditionalOnMissingBean" but without using spring-boot.

I am using Spring versions 5.3.13.

Is that possible? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by digging around spring-boot source code.
ConditionalOnBean will only work on beans defined inside a configuration (bean methods).
This is also recommended by spring-boot java doc for @ConditionalOnBean

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the
> application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this
> condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by
> another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

Here is the basics of the solution I came up with, this may be improved but the basics operate well.

The condition:

```
@Slf4j
class MissingBeanCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {
    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        var targetBeanType = metadata.getAnnotations()
                .get(ConditionalOnMissingBean.class)
                .getValue("value", Class.class)
                // TODO throw a more informative error
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Failed to evaluate MissingBeanCondition"));
        
        try {
            context.getBeanFactory().getBean(targetBeanType);
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            return true;
        }
       
        return false;
    }
}
```

The annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Conditional(MissingBeanCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalOnMissingBean {
    Class<?> value();
}
```

Usage example:

```
@Bean
@Singleton
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Provider.class)
public Provider myClass() {
    return new DefaultProvider();
}
```